# How to pass &arr to a function in c

Tags: c

I simply want to pass an `&arr` in C language.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( PARAMETER??? )
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    test(&arr);
    return 0;
}
```

How should I declare the parameter?

As it is of type `int (*)[8]`

I simply want to pass `&arr` in C language. I know I can pass `arr` and `length` argument, but how can I via this?

Comment: I doubt that you need to modify the pointer in that function, so I don't see why you would pass `&arr` here and not just `arr`.

Comment: In C, arrays are usually passed to functions by passing a pointer to the first element of the array, not a pointer to the entire array. That way, you have a pointer of type `int *` instead of the awkward pointer type `int (*)[8]`. If you pass `arr` instead of `&arr`, then you are effectively passing `&arr[0]`, because `arr` [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to `&arr[0]`.

Comment: @Cheatah There isn't really a pointer to modify. This is a scheme in C to make the interface to the fcn enforce an array of a fixed, compile-time known length. It has been mentioned in the past in stack overflow posts.

Comment: The answer is already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74284182/4386427 but I can't help wonder why you want to do that. What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As it is of type `int (*)[8]`

If you want to pass `&arr`, then that is exactly the type you need to declare the parameter as, eg:

```
void test(int (*param)[8])
{
    // use param as needed...
}
```

Comment: Of note, the first element of the array is `(*param)[0]`, not `param[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass array in function with array size. but you need to use `sizeof()` to calculate the size of array

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test( int arr[], size_t size_of_array )
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    size_t size_of_array = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  /* calculate of array size */
    test(arr, size_of_array );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this is not what was asked, I agree that this is probably what OP actually needed.

Comment: as per comment from @Cheetah, I edited data type from `int` to `size_t` for `size_of_array`. since `size_t` which is the unsigned integer. so it is guaranteed  to hold for array size/index. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array as an argument.

You can pass a pointer to its first element:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test( size_t n, int *p ) {       // `p` is a pointer an `int`.
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(p) );      // `sizeof( int* )`, 8 for me.
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(*p) );     // `sizeof( int )`, 4 for me.
   printf( "%d\n", p[0] );            // 1
   printf( "%d\n", p[1] );            // 2
}

int main( void ) {
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
   test( sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), arr );
}
```

Same thing in disguise:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test( size_t n, int p[n] ) {     // `p` is a pointer an `int`.
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(p) );      // `sizeof( int* )`, 8 for me.
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(*p) );     // `sizeof( int )`, 4 for me.
   printf( "%d\n", p[0] );            // 1
   printf( "%d\n", p[1] );            // 2
}

int main( void ) {
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
   test( sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), arr );
}
```

Finally, you could pass a pointer to the array:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test( size_t n, int (*p)[n] ) {  // `p` is a pointer to an `int[11]`
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(p) );      // `sizeof( int* )`, 8 for me.
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(*p) );     // `sizeof( int[11] )`, 44 for me.
   printf( "%d\n", (*p)[0] );         // 1
   printf( "%d\n", (*p)[1] );         // 2
}

int main( void ) {
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
   test( sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), &arr );
}
```

In any case, you will need the pass the size of the array if you need it, because it's not stored anywhere in the array itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it directly (not an address) to a function like

```
void test(int prm[restrict 8]);
```

It will not allow to pass `int arr[7]`, and will allow to pass `int arr[9]`, but you will not know the array size, all what you know, it has the size at least 8.

Comment: `restrict` says, roughly, the pointer will not be used to access data that is also access through a separate pointer. It has nothing to do with the size of the array. `int prm[static 8]` asserts the resulting pointer parameter is supposed to point to at least 8 elements. That is supposed to allow some optimization of code in the called function. As for its effect on calling code, it is [unenforced or weakly enforced by compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/dc4aj1TT8).